# Android Unit Test, context is passed between activities in tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, applicationcontext

I want to run a number of unit tests on a clean instance of my application and thought I could do that by creating an instance with getActivity and finish it at the end of the test. However, I noticed that the actions in the previous test had effect on the next one. I wrote the following simple application to reproduce the issue.

The test setup shows a number of tests where I get the activity and finish it in each test. During the creation of the activity a counter is incremented in the onCreate. I expect that it is 1 at all 3 tests but I see that it is 3 at the latest test. Somehow the context is reused.

Can somebody explain and show how I can test an application from scratch in each test?

```
import com.example.activitykeepscontext.MainActivity;

public class MainActivityTest  extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

   public MainActivityTest() {
        super("com.example.activitykeepscontext", MainActivity.class);
    }

   public void testCount1() {
       MainActivity mainActivity = getActivity();
       mainActivity.finish();
   }

   public void testCount2() {
       MainActivity mainActivity = getActivity();
       mainActivity.finish();
   }

   public void testCount3() {
       MainActivity mainActivity = getActivity();
       mainActivity.finish();
   }

}
```

This is the application:

```
package com.example.activitykeepscontext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AppData appData = (AppData)getApplicationContext();
        appData.count++;

        Log.i(TAG, "Count: " + appData.count);
    }
}
```

and this is the class used to pass the data via the application context.

```
package com.example.activitykeepscontext;

import android.app.Application;

public class AppData  extends Application {
    public int count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what yuo need is an [ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html), which gives you also the ability to inject an Application. ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 does not provide a way of injecting an Application and thus use the default for the Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I learned that Android doesn't really end the application with finish() but leaves it in the background. Upon reopening the context is reused, I wonder if that is intended. The solution is quite simple and that is initializing the variables that are passed via the application context in the onCreate(). This is always good practice. I expect that your solution will work as well since with ActivityUnitTestCase it is possible to clean the context each time.